# How can I combine these 2 Pandas dataframe linegraphs into a single matplotlib graph with 2 lines?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have a single dataframe called sentimentJoin that contains all the values I want to plot in a line graph. I have a single constant y-axis (time), which is a string containing when the data was pulled, and 2 x-axis (sentiment and close), but I cannot get them to plot against each other. I am able to plot them separately, but when I try to combine them in the code below, I am getting the error, "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '09:37'. I'm not sure why I can plot the 'time' string in the separated line graphs, but not the combined graph.

Any tips on what I could modify in the code?

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111, label="1")
ax2=fig.add_subplot(111, label="2", frame_on=False)

ax.plot(sentimentJoin['time'], sentimentJoin['sentiment'], color="C0")
ax.set_xlabel("x label 1", color="C0")
ax.set_ylabel("y label 1", color="C0")
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors="C0")
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors="C0")

ax2.plot(sentimentJoin['time'], sentimentJoin['close'], color="C0")
ax2.xaxis.tick_top()
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()
ax2.set_xlabel('x label 2', color="C1") 
ax2.set_ylabel('y label 2', color="C1")       
ax2.xaxis.set_label_position('top') 
ax2.yaxis.set_label_position('right') 
ax2.tick_params(axis='x', colors="C1")
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', colors="C1")
```

Data Shown Here:

```
close/   open/     unixTime/     time/  sentiment/
8109.1/ 8114.92/ 1524058380/     9:33/     -0.284848/
```

Comment: It'd be [super-helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you could share the code+data to produce the dataframe, or mock up a simpler dataframe, for us to experiment with. It *sounds* like `cryptoSentimentJoin['time']` is a bunch of plain strings, rather than proper Python/Pandas timestamps but we can't be sure.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, the dataframe should've been sentimentJoin['time'], I apologize. As for the contents of the dataframe, 'time' is being converted from a unix timestamp to the 'time' string. The unix timestamp is also contained in the dataframe.

Comment: @Learner ... please post data of *sentimentJoin* which illustrates better then textual explanation.

Comment: Yes, the best [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is where we can just paste the code into IPython (maybe after creating an input data file) and then tinkering.

Comment: Did you try `sentimentJoin.set_index('time')[['close', 'sentiment']].plot()`

Comment: Thank you piRSquared, a variation of your code worked.

I used `ax.plot(sentimentJoin.set_index('timestamp')['close'], color="C0")` and `ax2.plot(sentimentJoin.set_index('timestamp')['sentiment'], color="C0")` and was able to combine the line graphs